# Javascript function not excuting but the first instruction

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a weird question about I am losing my head over this, I have a JS function, that used to work perfectly until I went to the MVC model, the javascript function should reverse the colors of the navbar on a scroll, (the navbar is white with grey text when I scroll it should be grey with white text)

Here is the function code

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const mainNav = document.getElementById("navbar");

  if (this.window.pageYOffset > 0) {
    mainNav.classList.add("navscroll");
    mainNav.classList.add("navscroll a");
    mainNav.classList.add("navscroll #navcustom_1:hover");
    mainNav.classList.add("navscroll #navcustom_2:hover");
    mainNav.classList.add("navscroll #navcustom_3:hover");
  } else {
    mainNav.classList.remove("navscroll");
    mainNav.classList.remove("navscroll a");
    mainNav.classList.remove("navscroll #navcustom_1:hover");
    mainNav.classList.remove("navscroll #navcustom_2:hover");
    mainNav.classList.remove("navscroll #navcustom_3:hover");
  }
});
```

Before I scroll

[image]

After I scroll, only the first line is not working

[image]

The CSS code if it helps

```
.navscroll {
  background-color: #3f3f3f !important;
}

.navscroll a {
  color: white !important;
}

.navscroll #navcustom_1:hover {
  color: #b82be2 !important;
}

.navscroll #navcustom_2:hover {
  color: #e25822 !important;
}

.navscroll #navcustom_3:hover {
  color: #2e8b57 !important;
}

#navcustom_1:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #40d9ac;
  color: #b82be2;
}

#navcustom_2:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #40d9ac;
  color: #e25822;
}

#navcustom_3:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #40d9ac;
  color: #2e8b57;
}
```

The includes, in header.php which is required on all the other pages

```
<!-- ? CustomCssLink -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" />
<!-- ? JSLink -->
<script src="../JS/functions.js"></script>
```

Here's the navbar itself

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white sticky-top" id="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="containerF">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <h3>WildCampers</h3>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbarAuto">
```

I just don't understand why this's happening it's driving me crazy
if you need any other details that might help just let me know

Comment: Please edit your question and replace images with your current code.

Comment: @AnuragBhagsain it's always preferable to [use the stack snippets feature to create a runnable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) here in the question, instead of on another site.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad @VLAZ I didn't know that. I'm new to answering questions

Comment: @Triby done I changed it

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. classList.add can add classes. There shouldn't be any selectors in the string. It makes no sense so idk what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AnuragBhagsain I don't how is that, but I would do it to share the whole code

Comment: @GarrGodfrey the function select the navbar using its id when it detects the scroll it changes the class with the one mentioned in parameter, which change the look of it

Comment: that's what the first call to classList.add does. The other 3 aren't needed and may have undefined behavior.

Comment: The navscroll class is getting added, otherwise the links wouldn't turn white. You have some other style overriding the backgound color of the nav bar. Look up how conflicting styles are prioritized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have a conflicting style somewhere. It could be the order of the styles in your css, or perhaps another css is being included that is more specific. Increasing the specificity of the style is usually more effective than just using !important, since two styles can have !important.

```
#navbar.navscroll {
  background-color: #3f3f3f !important;
}
```

my hunch is adding the ID to the style will increase the specificity enough that the style will take effect.

ADDITIONALLY, you should remove these lines of code that may have undesirable behavior, if any:

```
mainNav.classList.add("navscroll a");
mainNav.classList.add("navscroll #navcustom_1:hover");
mainNav.classList.add("navscroll #navcustom_2:hover");
mainNav.classList.add("navscroll #navcustom_3:hover");
```

Comment: thank you man, indeed, the bootstrap css was overriding mine, it was included in the footer with the rest of the scripts, thank you very much!!